# Autocomplete in appended fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I'm trying to make autocomplete in appended field. Example:

1. I add dynamic fields to the form by clicking link with id="add_field"

   ```
   var counter = 0;
   $(function(){
       $('a#add_field').click(function(){
       counter += 1;
       $('#container').append(
           '<input id="field_' + counter + '" name="dynfields[]' + '" class="name" type="text" /><br />' );
       });
   });
   ```
2. make field autocomplete

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("input[class=name]").autocomplete({
       source:'searches/product_autocomplete.php',
       minLength:2
       });
   });
   ```

However it does not do autocomplete.
I have tried this in a static field with class="name" and it works. But it does not work in dynamic fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attach the autocomplete to the new element when you create it:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var counter = 0;
        $('#add_field').click(function () {
            counter += 1;
            $('<input id="field_' + counter + '" name="dynfields[]' + '" class="name" type="text" /><br />')
                .appendTo($('#container'))
                .autocomplete({
                    source: 'searches/product_autocomplete.php',
                    minLength: 2
                });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding dynamic HTML then it's not being loaded into the DOM on page load. You may need to attach an event after the page has loaded.

try:

```
var counter = 0; 
$(function(){
    $("#dataTable tbody" )on('click', 'tr', function()
     {
       counter += 1;
       $('#container').append(
        '<input id="field_' + counter + '" name="dynfields[]' + '" class="name" type="text" />
        <br />' );
});  });
```